# Android mneu icon to change

Tags: android, xml

I have now standard Android menu within it icon, I want to change standard icon.

From  [image]
 to [image]

Comment: so dont implement the action bar and create your own layout

Comment: that time I cannot to use standart menu open function

Comment: I need standart menu icon to change

Comment: Please do not change this icon. You are welcome to have a "gear" action bar item (e.g., to launch your settings activity), but do not replace the "..." with something else. Half of your users will never see the replaced icon, anyway, as their devices have off-screen MENU buttons, and so there is no overflow icon. Many of the other half will get confused as to why the "gear" is behaving so strangely. Your app may be prone to poor reviews (on the Play Store and elsewhere) as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Just choose an icon from your drawable folder. Open the XML file for your menu options, it should look like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="s"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
    android:title="Settings"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Then it is currently choosing the Android icon for settings. What you need to do is change the icon line to this:

```
android:icon="@drawable/settings"
```

It will then reference from your icons instead of Android's own ones. Obviously change the name in that line to fit what your icon is called. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This "menu item" is called Overflow. You need to modify your application style to change its appearance. Here's the default style:

```
<style name="Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@android:drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/action_menu_overflow_description</item>
</style>
```